# C++ Read in a file like a grid

Tags: c++

I'm coding in C++ and I'm trying to read in a file that I'd like to access certain chars at later. As in, what is the char at (line x, char y), at any given point in the file.

My only thought right now is to look for a newline character, and somehow index them so that I can refer back to newline x, check the length of a line, and pull a char at whatever position given the line length.

I'm not sure if that is a good approach or not.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (for character in line "lineNum" and column "columnNum"):

```
ifstream inf;
inf.open(filename); //filename being c-string

string str;
for (int i = 0; i < lineNum; i++)
{
     std::getline(inf, str); 
}
```

This way "str" stores the line you are interested in (automatically checks for newline character and stops).
Then you can use:

```
char chr = str[columnNum];
```

to store the character you want in "chr" variable. And don't forget:

```
inf.close();
```

Unfortunately, to my knowledge you need to repeat this process every time you want to access a character.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of something like this as well but I was hoping to avoid exactly what you mentioned, but it is nice to see it written out in code.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define FILENAME "File.txt"

class FileGrid {
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> Line;
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator LineIter;

    typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> StringMap;
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::const_iterator StringMapIter;


    void FillGrid(char* fileName) {
        grid.clear();
        std::ifstream in(FILENAME, std::ifstream::in);
        if (!in.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "problem reading " << FILENAME << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        std::string words;
        std::string word;
        std::stringbuf buffer;

        while (in.is_open() && std::getline(in, words)) {
            std::stringstream ss(words);
            Line line;
            while (ss >> word) {
                line.push_back(word);
            }

            grid.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    void PrintGrid() {
        StringMapIter b = grid.begin();
        StringMapIter e = grid.end();

        std::cout << "\t\tFile Content:" << std::endl;
        while(b != e) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < b->size(); ++i) {
                std::cout << b->operator[](i) << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            ++b;
        }
    }

    char const & GetChar(int lineNo, int charNo) {
        // LineNo checks etc
        Line const & line = grid[lineNo];
        for(std::string const & word : line ) {
            if(charNo > word.size() + 1) {
                charNo -= word.size() + 1;
            }
            else {
                return word[charNo];
            }
        }

        throw std::exception("charNo higher");
    }

private:
    StringMap grid;


};

void main() {

    FileGrid grid;
    grid.FillGrid(FILENAME);
    grid.PrintGrid();

    std::cout << grid.GetChar(0, 3); // should return first line, 4th character
}
```

Not the best code I've ever written but pretty much what I could do in a short time.

`FileGrid` handles reading and accessing the data. It reads the file line by line and stores it in a `std::vector`. When it finishes reading a line, it pushes that into another `std::vector`. In the end, we have a (sort of) 2D array of strings.

Again, not the best code and definitely not the most optimized code but the idea is still the same: read from the file line by line, separate each word and put them into an array of strings. If you can't use STL, you can dynamically create a 2D array for each line but since I don't know the specific requirements of your question, I just wrote something simple and bruteforce to show you the main way of storing grid of strings into the memory.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any specific requirements, I was just looking for ideas like this.

Answer (score -2):

As long as it works. But reading the entire file into memory, if that's an option, would be simpler.

Comment: Sure, I'm not familiar with how but I'll look into it. Is there then a better way to access characters at specific spots once the file is read into memory?

Comment: This could have been a comment.

Comment: The question is about the approach. Loading everything in a `vector<string>` or another similar structure is the simplest way, provided the grid isn't too big. Indexing works too.

Comment: @n.caillou The question is _off-topic_ in 1st place. Don't answer _off-topic_ questions. Comment if you want to help the OP though.